# Get scripthash for known scriptPubKey in python

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have to query addresses in ElectrumX server. How do I generate scripthash for a known scriptPubKey in python? If my bitcoin wallet address is 1P5ZEDWTKTFGxQjZphgWPQUpe554WKDfHQ ，I want to convert to scripthash